# Null sequence monotone decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $g$ be a rational function in $n$ variables $x_1,...,x_n$. Let $f_k$ be an exponential, logarithmic or power function for $k=1,...,n$. Let $f(x)=g(f_1(x),...,f_n(x))$ , and define a sequence by: $a_m=f(m)$. Assuming $\lim_{m\to\infty}a_m=0$ and $a_m\geq 0$ , does it follow that $a_m$ must be monotone non-increasing for $m$ sufficiently large?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true. The function $f$ belongs to   Hardy's class of *logarithmico-exponential functions*, and therefore is monotone on $[M,\infty)$ for sufficiently large $M$. Consequently, the sequence $a_m$ is eventually monotone. Due to the assumptions $a_m\to 0$ and $a_m\ge 0$, it must be non-increasing.

Some references:

- [MathOverflow post by David Speyer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/3075)
- [Some open problems on multiple ergodic averages](http://www.math.uoc.gr/~nikosf/OpenProblems/Hardy.pdf) by Nikos Frantzikinakis, with many references